# Torque from drag force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, drag, rigid-body-dynamics

A diver (assumed to be a rigid body) leaping off the springboard experiences no external torque from gravity since gravity acts at the COM. Air resistance doesn't act on every particle of the diver so it shouldn't act at the COM. Where does the drag force act for a rigid body? I suspect it acts through the line of action of the center of mass of the cross sectional area.

Comment: Aerodynamic drag is a result of interaction between a solid and fluid, so it will logically occur where those two meet. Consider that the center of mass of an object does not actually need to have any mass itself. A hula hoop, for example, has a COM at the center of the ring, even though no part of the hula hoop exists there. Drag wouldn't operate on the COM directly, as there's no part of the hula hoop there to drag upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recognize that aerodynamic forces on the rigid body are not mainly a function of the state of motion of the body, but rather mainly a function of the state of the surrounding fluid. You might have two different experiments with the same rigid body (shape) moving at the same velocity, but two very different fluid flows around it. Hence, the aerodynamic forces are also different.

So what really matters is the distribution of local forces at the surface of the rigid body, and due to the infinitesimal nature of the locality of these forces, they are given as force per surface area, which is called "stress".

In a frictionless fluid there are undirected stresses due to static pressure, and stresses due to the inertia of the fluid. In a viscous fluid there are additional shear stresses that cause the losses. All the stresses that prevail at a certain point are given as the stress tensor at that point
$$\hat \sigma = (\sigma_{ij})$$
where $i,j=1\dots 3$ are the coordinate directions. In order to get the force acting on a surface, you have to integrate the stress tensor over a surface, subject to the local surface normal $\vec n$. In other words, the total force on a rigid body with surface $A$ is given by
$$\vec F=\oint_A \hat \sigma(\vec n) dA$$
Likewise, the total torque on the rigid body with respect to the chosen origin is given by
$$\vec T=\oint_A \vec r \times\hat \sigma(\vec n) dA$$
If you decompose the location of the surface point $\vec r$ into the center of mass $\vec r_{CM}$ and the surface location $\vec r_{rel}$ relative to the center of mass, that is
$$\vec r=\vec r_{CM}+\vec r_{rel}$$
the torque takes the form
$$\vec T=\vec r_{CM} \times\oint_A \hat \sigma(\vec n) dA+\oint_A \vec r_{rel} \times\hat \sigma(\vec n) dA=\vec r_{CM} \times \vec F+\vec T_{rel}$$
Hence, if you choose your origin for the force/torque calculation as the center of mass of the rigid body, torque is just the one that causes the usual rigid body's angular  acceleration according to
$$T=T_{rel}=I\dot \omega$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia around the respective axis of rotation. If you don't take the center of mass as the origin, you have to subtract the center of mass torque $\vec r_{CM} \times \vec F$ from $\vec T$ before you formulate the rigid body equations of motion. Note that the force does not depend at all on the choice of origin, only torque does.

I think your confusion comes from viewing a force as acting at a point or along a line of action. While this view has its right of existence in simple rigid body mechanics, as a very specific way of expressing the roles of torque and force in seemingly one entity (force "pinned" to a point), it is not very "continuum-friendly". What really happens when you apply a force "off-center" of the center of mass is that you apply a shear stress (which is what a tangential force actually is) at the surface of the continuum of the body, which causes the resulting torque relative to the center of mass as the chosen origin.

So, in order to explicitly answer your question: yes, the drag force acts at the center of mass line of action, by its very definition, and yes, there usually also occur "drag torques", like shown above.